# Eclipse Oxygen project linking to class files instead of source files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I have 3 Java projects in my workspace in Eclipse (Oxygen). The projects are A, B and Utils. The Utils project is used by both A and B. If I go into the `Java Build Path` for either of those projects, I can see the Utils project listed under the `Projects` tab option (`required projects on the build path`).

If I hold ctrl key and hover over functions, classes etc. that belong to Utils project from a source file in project A, then the links take me to the relevant source file in Utils project. If I do the same in project B, it always attempts to open the class file, not the source.

Is there something else I need to configure in project B to link the source files in Utils?

Comment: Make sure in the Java Build Path of project B, in the tab _Libraries_, the bin/class folder of the Utils project is not added as a class folder.

Comment: Thanks, the JAR I've been generating for the Utils project was listed in the Libraries tab as an external dependency. Removing it solved the problem. If you wanna throw that into an answer, I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, in the ***Java Build Path* of project B**, in the **tab *Libraries***, the **`bin`/class folder** of the **Utils project** is **not** added as a **class folder**. The dependency to the Utils project should be defined in the *Projects* tab only.